# SCIP makefile for c++

Tags: makefile, scip

I am beginner in using SCIP. I want to solve a simple MILP written in C++. I developed a simple makefile to compile and run my model but I realized there many nested header files when you call SCIP. I was wondering there might be a sample makefile to solve MILPin C++ using SCIP.
Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use a makefile from one of the SCIP examples, e.g. scip/examples/TSP/Makefile. The C++ files of your project should be then added to the MAINOBJ variable.